# Break inheritance from the parent Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, ootb

I would like to break the inheritance permission to the List/Item without inheriting parent object permissions in OOTB without using Code.

I can break the inheritance with the help of PS `SPListItem.BreakRoleInheritance($false)` without copying the parent object permissions, but here I need to do this from my site.

Comment: @prasadwt Yes. Do you have any reference? If you can please share with me.

Comment: (1)http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/break-inheritance-and-assign-unique-permissions-to-list-in-sharepoint-2016-and-o/ (2) http://www.interfacett.com/blogs/create-custom-security-level-sharepoint-site-apply-users/   (3) https://collab365.community/how-to-security-trim-search-results-in-sharepoint-2013/